# UIImageView not updating new image after selecting that image from picker. Not even printing info on didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Everything seems to be working, the image is clicked, it selects the image. The info is also printed on the console and it displays the information there. It just doesn't upload my profilepic's image. There's no crash and I tried without the updating the main thread as well.
I'm using Swift 5.
I used SnapKit for constraints and it seems to work perfectly fine.

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import Firebase
import AlamofireImage

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var profilePic: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        image.layer.cornerRadius =  image.frame.height/2
        image.layer.masksToBounds = true
        image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let img = ProfileViewController.scaleUIImageToSize(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user"), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        image.image = img
        return image
    }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSubviews()
        setUpGestures()
    }
func setupSubviews() {

        //Profile Image
        view.addSubview(profilePic)

        self.profilePic.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.topMargin.equalTo(view.snp_topMargin).offset(5)
            make.left.leftMargin.equalTo(view.snp_leftMargin).offset(2)
        }

}

    func setUpGestures() {
        let tapForProfilePic = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfilePic))
        profilePic.addGestureRecognizer(tapForProfilePic)

    }

extension ProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @objc func handleSelectProfilePic() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        print("\(info)")
        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
                let img = image.af_imageScaled(to: size)
                self.profilePic.image = img
                self.profilePic.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }
        else if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
                let img = image.af_imageScaled(to: size)
                self.profilePic.image = img
                self.profilePic.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: does this return nil? 
let img = image.af_imageScaled(to: size)

Comment: It doesn't print anything inside the if statements, not even the image

Comment: then this here: info[.originalImage]  is returning null? Check if that enum is correct.

Comment: It prints <UIImage: 0x28046f950> size {200, 200} orientation 0 scale 3.000000